# Adding a <br> tag between text in php

Tags: php

I would like to translate these two lines of text together as one string. Basically I would like to escape the quotes and add a `<br>` tag like my attempt below.

```
<?php
   global $jwp_lang;
   echo __("This is the first line"<br>"this is the second line", $jwp_lang['basictheme']);?>
   ?>
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Try removing the double quotes aroung <br> tag.

Comment: why "<br>" ? try only <br> global $jwp_lang;
   echo __("This is the first line <br> this is the second line", $jwp_lang['basictheme']); will work!

Answer (score 2):

Please check below code

```
<?php
     global $jwp_lang;
     echo __("This is the first line<br>this is the second line", $jwp_lang['basictheme']);
?>
```

Comment: I've got a feeling the desired output is two lines, each actually wrapped in quote marks as it's stated *I would like to escape the quotes* which would explain the odd `"` marks around the `<br>` tag ... I could be wrong though.

Comment: I've got a feeling the OP needs to explain the question better. For all I know they're trying to output &lt;br&gt;

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
global $jwp_lang;
echo __("This is the first line <br> this is the second line" ,$jwp_lang['basictheme']);
```